# Cannot create connection:Could not connect: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I am getting the below error while getting the connection from maria db:

```
DEBUG com.utilities.db.ConnectionPoolImpl - Exception Occured in connection: Cannot create connection:Could not connect: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
        at com.utilities.db.ConnectionPoolImpl.run(ConnectionPoolImpl.java:128)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                    |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.35-80.0              |
| protocol_version        | 10                       |
| slave_type_conversions  |                          |
| version                 | 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 |
| version_comment         | Raspbian 9.0             |
| version_compile_machine | armv7l                   |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnueabihf   |
| version_malloc_library  | system jemalloc          |
| version_ssl_library     | YaSSL 2.4.2              |
| wsrep_patch_version     | wsrep_25.19              |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I am using java to connect to db.

```
Class.forName("org.drizzle.jdbc.DrizzleDriver");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(""jdbc:drizzle://" + ADDRESS + ":" + PORT + "/" + DB", userName, password);

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:drizzle://" + DBProperties.ADDRESS + ":" + DBProperties.PORT + "/?allowMultiQueries=true",
                        DBProperties.USER, DBProperties.PASS)

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.drizzle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>drizzle-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am not sure why i am getting this can anyone help me?

Comment: Please, could you post the version of the back-end software and the version of the client driver that you are using?

Comment: @Jorge_B i have updated the query in my post.Please let me know if anything more required.

Comment: Just following the book: have you observed all the recommendations here? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/  Maybe the drizzle driver is outdated?

Comment: @Jorge_B thanks for the reference but, as per your understanding what i am missing here?

Comment: Answering down in full length ^^

Answer (score 1):

Please try and follow the recommendations in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/

I would remove drizzle driver from your maven dependencies and include the latest version of the mariaDB connector

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I would replace your client code for the official example:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/DB?user=foo&password=bar");
```

With the appropriate port, user, etc. values.  I hope that you find it useful